# StringWriter write to folder

Tags: java, directory, stringwriter

Good Afternoon.  I want to use the StringWriter to write the new file to a network folder.  Can anyone give me some examples using the code below on how to do this?   It's my first time working with the StringWriter class.

```
    public static final void newOutput(Document xml) throws Exception {
        Transformer tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
        tf.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");
        tf.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-8");
        tf.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
        StringWriter out = new StringWriter();
        tf.transform(new DOMSource(xml), new StreamResult(out));

        /*
         * need to update to write to folder
         */
        System.out.println(out.toString());

    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried a `FileOutputStream`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static final void newOutput(Document xml) throws Exception {
    Transformer tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
    tf.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");
    tf.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-8");
    tf.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
    DOMSource source = new DOMSource(xml);
    // Use StreamResult to write to a file to current directory
    StreamResult out = new StreamResult(new File("test.txt"));
    // to print to console
    // StreamResult out = new StreamResult(System.out);
    tf.transform(source, out);

    /*
     * console output is redirected to SRC folder to check format
     * need to update to write to folder
     */
    System.out.println(out.toString());

}
```

Comment: Thanks, it says that StreamWriter cant be a resolved type.  Do I need to create a StreamWriter Class? @openmike

Comment: Yes, import it. Use import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;

Comment: eclipse is asking me to create a class or change it to StringWriter.  I do have it imported @openmike

Comment: StreamResult is okay. Use import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;